# How can I set a content type in my json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my controller:

```
render json: gerencia.pay_charge(params: params, body: payment)
```

My response header return this:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
```

How can I set the content-type for this:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Are you trying to render json but change the content type to HTML? This is odd and would be confusing to browsers and clients of your application. You have `json` set in your `render` call. That is why the content type is JSON.

Comment: I need do it to test a specific thing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are testing?

Comment: I'm trying integrate my app with a API from a private company, but it doen't works. So this company's support told me to do that to test if it will works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring that you are delivering `json`, declare that you are delivering `html` like so:

```
render html: gerencia.pay_charge(params: params, body: payment)
```

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-html

However, If you just want to display it nicely in your browser, I suggest you install a plugin that can pretty-print JSON data and stick with rendering JSON.